# How can I do a comparison of more than one value in a collection?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I do a comparison as follows:

```
var searchValue = 'Apple'
var searchValue2 = 'Orange'
var index = $scope.sEntitiesListTest.findIndex(x => x.ItemText === searchValue);
```

Can I do a comparison of more than one value, like

```
var index = $scope.sEntitiesListTest.findIndex(x => x.ItemText === searchValue && x => x.ItemValue = searchValue2);
```

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not the arrow function (`=>`) in the second comparison. Also you are mistakenly using assignment operator (`=`) instead of the compassion operation (`==` or `===`):

```js
var EntitiesListTest = [{ItemText: "Test Text", ItemValue: "Test Value"},{ItemText: "Apple", ItemValue: "Orange"}]
var searchValue = 'Apple';
var searchValue2 = 'Orange';
var index = EntitiesListTest.findIndex(x => x.ItemText === searchValue && x.ItemValue == searchValue2); 
console.log(index);
```

Comment: But what if I had somethingwhere ItemValue was an array of objects ? Would I need to scan those and check or is there a equivalent firstordefault like in linq ?

Comment: @Mel, you can use `includes()` like `x.ItemValue.includes(searchValue2)` which will return `true` if `searchValue2` is present in `x.ItemValue`.